# My MainActivity Java file in android studio is not recognising id's of editText and TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my xml code of my UI. I have tried changing the Id's of my textview and editText many times. It didn't work though. I have got two activities here, my first activity is able to recognise the Id's of second activity but, it is not recognising the current activity's Id's.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="443dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="73dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="129dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="129dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="194dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="194dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="129dp"
    android:onClick="sendmessage"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="108dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
    android:text="Reply Received"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="118dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="118dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="131dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />
```

[Screenshot of my mainactivity.java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Qyh.jpg)

Comment: Share the code of your Java/kotlin file from which you are accessing these components.

Comment: Restart Your Android studio to clear caches

Comment: File-->Invalidate caches & restart

Comment: My java file is attached as screenshot thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The R.java file is the same for the whole package, so the first activity can use the id's of second activity but it will not be found at runtime. In this case the problem might be in android studio. You can try to clean and rebuild the project. I think that would solve the problem.